# GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler minimum bandwidth

Tags: java, netty

I've been using the GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler class to control traffic on my pipeline. It works like a charm, I get the expected average throughput on writes and reads, and its awesome that I can dynamically change it.

I've noticed that when I set the limit to something < 65536, it will only honor to that limit.

I have a sample client that generates random traffic around 300k/s, and setting the read/write (it's a proxy) limits to < 64k it will set it to 64k every time. Is this intentional?

I'm using netty 4.1.0.RC3 and here's how I create the TrafficShapingHandler:

```
this.trafficHandler = new GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler(workerGroup,0,0,0,0,1000,1000);
```

Later I'll set the new values for globalWrites and GlobalReads using trafficHandler.configure()

Is this due some buffer internally?

Regards